# Jquery Help, On click, make the others dark

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i do it in jquery such that when any of the items that is being clicked in .cd-item, i want the non-clicked ones to appear dark.

The active mode should have opacity 1, where else the not clicked ones will have a class "darkbackground". I'm still quite new in javascript so appreciate if anyone could help.

So example, if david beckham is being clicked, rooney and kaka should be overlay black. If rooney is clicked, david beckham and kaka should be overlay black and so on.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYdVOy)

```
$(".cd-item a").click(function(){
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
   $(".cd-item a").addClass("darkbackground");
});
```

Thankyou, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `.not()`

```
$(".cd-item a").click(function(){
   $(".cd-item a").removeClass("darkbackground");
   $(".cd-item a").not($(this)).addClass("darkbackground");
});
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpbNVb

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need:

```
var $items=$(".cd-item a");
$items.click(function(){
   var $this=$(this);
   $items.removeClass("darkbackground");
   $this.addClass("darkbackground");
});
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyebRr)